# Outlook Add-In ComException on GetItemFromID()

Tags: c#, com, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an **Outlook 2013 Add-in** in which I process incoming emails:

```
void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ... other code ...
   Application.NewMailEx += GetEmail;
   ...
}

void GetEmail(string ID)
{
   try
   {
      var email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(ID) as Outlook.MailItem; // COMExeption
      var email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(ID);  // No casting - COMException 
   }
   ...
}
```

When new emails coming say from an outside (SMTP) email address, the emails are handled just fine. While testing, when I send a Calendar Meeting request, when that mail arrives, I get the following exception:

```
[Exception Type]: 
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 
 [Aggregate Exception]: 
 The message you specified cannot be found. 
 [Stack Trace]: 
    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.GetItemFromID(String EntryIDItem, Object EntryIDStore)
   at EmailHelper.ThisAddIn.GetEmail(String entryId) in c:\EmailHelper\ThisAddIn.cs:line 44
```

I've tried a couple of different workarounds, but no luck, an exception is always thrown, e.g.

1. Calling `GetItemFromID(ID, IDStore)`;
2. Calling `GetItemFromID(ID, Type.Missing)`;

What might I be missing?

Comment: What the actual ID value? Did you check out the real item's entry id? Do you have a corresponding item in your Inbox?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I have updated my question w/ further details re: the _StartUp() event handler. The actual ID is a long string, and when I look at the StoreID, it is even longer. Does this help?

Comment: Did you try to find a corresponding item in your Inbox? Does it exist?

Comment: Yes, if you mean if I can visually see the email on the main Inbox. As a quick test, if I sent myself a Calendar invitation, when I switch over to my Inbox, why does it fail with the above logic? How does one handle this then for NewEmailEx?

Answer (score -1):

Meeting request is not a message, but your code assumes it is a MailItem object. Meeting requests are represented by the MeetingItem object.

Use "is" or "as"  operators or retrieve the Class property using reflection to figure out what kind of object it is.

Comment: I understand that not all of the items are of type MailItem.  If I just attempt, var email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(ID);, a COMException is still thrown with the code above. I don't understand why by just passing a string for ID, that the next line that executes, i.e. no other code in between, thrown that COMException?

Comment: Are you sure the item was not moved by a rule? Can you copy the value of the entry id to the clipboard and try to use it in OutlookSpy (click IMAPISession | OpenEntry tab)?

Answer (score -1):

Same as emily_bma. And the cast to `EmailItem` or whatever has nothing to to with the `COMException` raised which appears to come at random. Sometimes you get this error and sometimes not. It's as if the notification is coming before the message is registered. Of course there is strictly no rule in my Outlook which is a plain new instance for development and test purpose only.

So after a few tries and readings, it occurred to me that using the following code instead of `Application.Session.GetItemFromID` actually provides much better result:

```
Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var item = nameSpace.GetItemFromID(entry.Trim(), Type.Missing);
```

As for the complete source code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
    Application.NewMailEx += Application_NewMailEx;
}

void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
{
#if !OLD_METHOD
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
#endif
    string[] arr = EntryIDCollection.Split(',');
    foreach(string entry in arr)
    {
#if OLD_METHOD
        var item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(entry.Trim(), Type.Missing);
#else
        var item = nameSpace.GetItemFromID(entry.Trim(), Type.Missing);
#endif
        // COMException is thrown there quite often when entry is a meeting.

        if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            // ... Do something with the email
        }
        else if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            // ... Do something with the appointment
        }
        else if (item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
        {
            // ... Do something with the meeting
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between Application.Session and Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") in a COM addin.The only difference is when your are using OOM from an external app - immediately after creating an instance of the Outlook.Application object, Application.Session will return null, and you'd have to call Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") followed by Namespace.Logon.

Comment: Well indeed. Here is the sequence of actions which reproduces the problem every time: set up a meeting from an external mail client and add the outlook account as required attendee, upload mail from outlook, accept meeting, cancel meeting in external client, upload mail from outlook: COM Exception. I hope it helps figuring it out since I have tried everything on my end including registering and tracing every single event available.

Comment: L'exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException n'a pas été gérée par le code utilisateur
  HResult=-2147221233
  Message=Impossible de trouver le message que vous avez spécifié.
  Source=Microsoft Outlook
  ErrorCode=-2147221233
  StackTrace:
       à Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace.GetItemFromID(String EntryIDItem, Object EntryIDStore)
       à ActivityReport.OutlookAddIn.ThisAddIn.Application_NewMailEx(String EntryIDCollection) dans c:\Users\T0129842\Source\Repos\ActivityReport\ActivityReport\ActivityReport.OutlookAddIn\ThisAddIn.cs:ligne 39
  InnerException:

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND, which means the item was already deleted or moved.

Comment: But there is no reason to get this error. I also got this exception a few times when receiving an e-mail that stays in my inbox.